# Running PHPUnit uses excessive disk space

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit, drupal-8

Each time I run a PHPUnit test, somewhere around 2.5 Gigs of disk space disappears.  This has been happening for a couple of weeks and at least 40 Gigs of space has vanished.  I am using PHPUnit 7.5.20 on Ubuntu but the Disk Usage Analyzer shows no significant changes in disk usage.  The tests I am running are for a Drupal contributed module.  This is the command.

`sudo -u www-data -E ../../vendor/bin/phpunit --group simplenews`

In the phpunit.xml file, only values for SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL, SIMPLETEST_DB and BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY have been changed and the output directory only uses 160 Megs.

I'm hoping someone has had this problem or at least understands why it's happening it and knows why so much disk space is disappearing.  After running out of space and expanding my partition by 30 Gigs last week, I'm down to 4.4 Gigs.

Comment: Are you using xdebug? It could be possible that your profiler is turned on. I know it produces a lot of data so could be useful to check

Comment: @mickadoo I haven't been using PHPUnit that long.  As far as I can tell from the phpunit.xml file and phpinfo(), xdebug is not being used and probably not installed.  The weird thing about this situation is that the amount of disk space used by my user's home folder has remained constant while the total disk space available has dropped.

Comment: If `phpinfo()` isn't showing xdebug then that rules it out. Another thing often taking up a lot of space can be logs, have you checked the size of files in your log directory? I see you tagged ubuntu, you could have a look at all the files in `/var/log`

Comment: @mickadoo /var/log is only using 2.8 Gigs.

Comment: That's good you found a solution, looks like there's good documentation out there for disabling / limiting the bin log files https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-mysql-binary-log/

Comment: @mickadoo What really fooled me and what I still don't understand is why the Ubuntu 'Disk Usage Analyzer' showed the /var folder using only 6 Gigs when it was using at least 70 Gigs.  It must be some Linux admin wizardry.  Anyway, thanks for the link.  I have already adjusted the binary log maximum size!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  In the `/var/lib/mysql` folder, I found 60+ Gigs of binary log files.  I cleared them with the `RESET MASTER` command.  I don't have extensive experience with PHPUnit so I'm not sure why this happened but that was my solution just in case it helps someone else.